# Export / re-obtain non-existent managed package

Tags: appexchange, backup

Back in 2013 my company procured a module called Web2Contact, produced by Topline Strategies(company), and unfortunately that module is no longer available through the AppExchange, or anywhere on google.

We have a production environment that still has it installed, however we are wanting to move over to a new setup, but keep the existing workflows. Which means we have to re-install this dependency.

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?  How do I get the install file off of salesforce's production environment, so that it can be re-obtained in a new salesforce instance, when it doesn't exist anywhere except our current installation?

Comment: I was able to locate a possible solution, and wanted to share, to further expose the question. It suggests recompiling it using the migration tool and IDE, which is a few steps further than I had hoped to have to go.
.............
[Duplicating a Managed package](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008upjIAA)

Comment: Not clear what you mean by module. An installed managed package that is normally distributed through the AppExchange can't be copied locally. However, if you can see the bodies of the classes and triggers then you could copy it, though you should also check that such action is within the license terms.

Comment: Thanks, that is along the lines of what I was thinking as well. I know we own a license for it, whether it was free at the time or with a purchase I am unsure. I reached out to the origin company for details, and haven't heard back yet.
It's definitely a managed package, with hidden component sources. Out of curiosity , what do you make of this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_retrieve_packaged.htm
It looks to me like the migration tool can migrate managed packages, no?

Comment: Yeah it reads like it should work but if it did it would cut across what I expect in terms of hiding of code. Suggest you give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: The company who created the package is your best bet. From the technology side, installation just requires a URL for a package version (and usually a password) and not necessarily an AppExchange entry. But they may have commercial reasons for not wanting any more installations.